# xdebug with php 7 on ubuntu apache2 not working

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-14.04, xdebug, php-7

actually had that problem and took me allot of time to figure out the solution: (if any previous php versions where installed, make sure to first get completely rid of them. if necessary purge and reinstall apache2 and php7)

first:

```
> sudo apt-get install php-xdebug
```

then edit the php.ini file of php 7 :

```
> sudo gedit /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
```

and just on the bottom add:

```
xdebug.remote_enable = On
```

save and of course then:

```
> sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: furthermore to disable XDebug temporarily:
> sudo phpdismod xdebug
or
> sudo phpenmod xdebug

Comment: By installing xdebug via `sudo apt-get install php-xdebug` and adding `xdebug.remote_enable = On` to my php.ini it's worked on Ubuntu 16.04 with PHP7.0 installed and netbeans, thank you any way.

Answer (score 2):

## Download stable release of xdebug 2.4.0

```
wget -c "http://xdebug.org/files/xdebug-2.4.0.tgz"
```

## Extract archive

```
tar -xf xdebug-2.4.0.tgz

cd xdebug-2.4.0/
```

## Build extension

```
phpize
./configure
make && make install
```

## Enable the extension

```
echo "zend_extension=xdebug.so" > /etc/apache2/mods-available/xdebug.ini

ln -sf /etc/apache2/mods-available/xdebug.ini /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/20-xdebug.ini
ln -sf /etc/apache2/mods-available/xdebug.ini /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/20-xdebug.ini

service php7.0-fpm restart
```

## Check it

```
php -m | grep -i xdebug
```

## It should print:

```
xdebug
Xdebug
```